# GNOME Title Bars Minimise

Tags: gnome

I am currently using GNOME, but I am having an aesthetic problem with the title bars.

When I, for example, use Firefox, I have the GNOME menu bar at the top, then I have the window menu, then I have the application:

[image]

It just makes for a very ugly triple layer. Is there any way to customise these menu bars to make them look nicer?